I am trying to extract pptx slide based on some text given and extract the complete slide using python pptx
from pptx import Presentation

def copy_slide_by_number(source_pptx_path, target_pptx_path, slide_number):
    # Open the source presentation
    source_pptx = Presentation(source_pptx_path)

    # Create a new presentation
    target_pptx = Presentation()

    # Copy the specified slide to the target presentation
    source_slide = source_pptx.slides[slide_number - 1]  # Adjust index to 0-based
    target_pptx.slides._sldIdLst.append(source_slide._element)

    # Save the target presentation
    target_pptx.save(target_pptx_path)

if __name__ == "__main__"
    source_pptx_path = "sample.pptx"
    target_pptx_path = "target_presentation.pptx"
    slide_number_to_copy = 9  # Change to the slide number you want to copy
    copy_slide_by_number(source_pptx_path, target_pptx_path, slide_number_to_copy)

I tried to copy the slide number to new pptx slide. But it is giving blank slide. Kindly let me know if you need more details on this. Thanks in Advance!!

Copying a slide is not built into python-pptx. It would involve copying all the shapes. And even then it might not be faithful visually.

Hi, if it answered your question you might as well mark it as correct .
